# Module not found: Can't resolve '../../images/jelly' in 'C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\cake-app\src\Components\Product'

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, components, babeljs

**Please can someone help me fix this error. I don't understand the reason of the error**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import CustomButton from "../CustomButton/CustomButton"; 
import logo from "../../images/jelly"; // svg icon  
// I also tried this method but I got the same error
// import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../images/jelly"; 


const Product = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
            {/* <Logo></Logo> */}
            <div className="content">
                <h4>Chocolate</h4> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
             </div>
             <CustomButton>$20 | Order Now </CustomButton>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Product

const Wrapper = styled.div``
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxHZf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add .svg in the file name: `import logo from "../../images/jelly.svg";`